# A saved QGIS project doesn't show any layers

Tags: qgis, qgs

I was working with a lot of layers on a QGIS project. I saved it and when I opened the file it doesn't show any layers. The .qgis is not empty, weighing 1,7Kb (I have other with 500Kb working well) but when I open the project it only shows the names of groups I made to manage the layers on Panel Layer.

I have try to use older versions of the project and they dont work either.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Open it in a text editor and check content. Without seeing the file, we can't help you

Comment: Have the source layers changed where they exist or maybe you did not save the project file.  As aldo_tapia suggested opening the .qgs file in a text editor and checking the layer sources may provide you some hints if they were set.

Comment: Were the layers temporary scratch layers? You'd know because when you create a temporary scratch layer there's a popup warning that the layer will be deleted when you close the project.

Comment: Suggesting the obvious, but are the groups collapsed? Click the little arrow next to the group name or click the "Expand All" button on the layer panel.

Comment: Thanks to all  for your responses, I was expecting that one problem with saves was already known. Finally, I have decided it was a problem while I was saving the file, cause all the causes you said up here have been checked and there is nothing out of normal: I didnt changed any file from the folders, the layers weren't temporary ones and the groups weren't collapsed.

I took an older versión and did all again, next time i will try to be sure i saved properly the project. Thanks